# converge of ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

for x(t) solution of $\dot{x}=f(x)$, f(x)  differentiable and the derivative continuous.

> show that $lim_{t\to{\infty}}x(t)=+-\infty $ or $lim_{t\to{\infty}}x(t)=$stationary point

it can visualized through a graph but Im not sure how to prove it in a formal way
thanks ahead

Answer (score 2):

this is true because all the constant solution $A = f^{-1}(0)$ is bounded. therefore if $x(0)$ outside $A,$ then $\lim_{t \to \infty}x(t) = \pm \infty$ and if it is between two points of $A,$ then $\lim_{t \to \infty} x(t)$ one of the constant solutions.